# How to prove the following using De-Moivre's Theorem along with knowledge of complex numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

This was a trig based complex number problem set I came across while learning about De-Moivre's or more specifically its applications. The question is as follows:

Q. If $\sin(a) + \sin(b) + \sin(c) = 0$ and $\cos(a) + \cos(b) + \cos(c) = 0$, prove that:

$1.\sin(2a) + \sin(2b) + \sin(2c) = \cos(2a) + \cos(2b) + \cos(2c) = 0$

$2. \sin(3a) + \sin(3b) + \sin(3c) = 3\sin(a + b + c)$

$3. \cos(3a) + \cos(3b) + \cos(3c) = 3\cos(a + b + c)$

I am looking for purely complex numbers based solutions. I am already aware of multiple ways to solve these through basic trig.

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to $e^{ia}+e^{ib}+e^{ic}=0$, if you take $0=(e^{ia}+e^{ib}+e^{ic})^2=e^{2ia}+e^{2ib}+e^{2ic}+2(e^{ia}e^{ib}+e^{ia}e^{ic}+e^{ib}e^{ic})$ and you can prove (which I can't for now) prove that the second term is $0$ then you are done. Anyways something in that direction might work.

Comment: I had already tried this manipulation along with several others. Proving that second term = 0 is something I'm not able to do. Based on similar logic there are several such 'second terms' that if I were able to prove = 0, it would do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here goes.

Note that $cos(a) +cos(b) +cos(c) +i(sin(a) +sin(b) +sin(c) =0=e^{ia}+e^{ib}+e^{ic}$. Let these exponential terms be called $A, B, C$ respectively.

1. We have $A+B+C=0$. Taking the conjugate gives $1/A + 1/B + 1/C=0$.

Now try squaring the first relation: $A^2+B^2+C^2+2(AB+BC+CA)=0=A^2+B^2+C^2+2ABC(1/A+1/B+1/C)$. The last terms is zero so drops out. Now note that $A^2=e^{i2a}$ etc., which if you expand out the real and imaginary parts with Euler's identity leads you to the answer.

2, 3. Try cubing the relation $A+B+C=0$. We get $A^3+B^3+C^3+3(A^2B+AB^2+A^2+AC^2+B^2C+BC^2)+6ABC=0$

That big term there simplifies to $3(AB(A+B)+BC(B+C)+CA(C+A))$, and if you use $A+B+C=0$ again, this becomes $3(-ABC-ABC-ABC)=-9ABC$.

Plugging this into the cubed relation gives $A^3+B^3+C^3=3ABC$, which simplifies to the required answer.

P.S. In case your profile is still relevant - good luck for the JEE! :D

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I was looking for. I seem to always not notice the fact that we can take conjugates to get new relations that work well. I managed to get till the A + B + C = 0 and square it quite easily and reached a similar step for the cubed equation as well. Your method bridged the gap really well! Also, thanks for the good wishes!